# <a href=""> not working in IE but does in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, modernizr

So I am trying to get the this HTML page to work, its in `CSS & HTM`L. When I try to click the `"a href="link here"` it doesn't work however if I open the window in Chrome vs. IE it works fine. Any idea as to why? The code is below for the `HTML` I can post the `CSS` if needed. The links below are not the actual links. The real links are going to a file on my pc/share drive. I am trying to load an HTA which is why it needs done in IE not chrome and no hrefs will work in IE with this for some reason no matter if its a https:// or anything it jsut doesn't work in IE.

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7243260-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script');
  ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1><img src="logo.png" width="500" height="180"></h1>
  </header>
  <div class="component">
    <h2>Downtime</h2>
    <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
    <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">Menu</button>
    <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Futuremark\SystemInfo" target="_blank"><span>Click Me</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Nav Structure -->
  </div>
  <section>
    <h1>
      <center>About</center>
    </h1>
    <p>Cool text here guys :)
      <br>
      <br> Even cooler text :).
    </P>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: When using Stackoverflow.com for example, `HTTPS://` or `HTTP://` is required for the link to actually work in IE. You can't just write "google.com" in `href` and expect it to work all the time. Example: `<a href="https://www.google.com">This link should work!</a>`

Comment: I just put the links as an example, I should have stated that. All the files being loaded are on a "share drive" or the pc essentially. so it will be like lap000123/folder1/folder2 etc. Ill update that in.

Comment: Just put down the filenames from which the HTML doc originates. I.E. there are two folders, "fonts" and "stylesheets". Your doc is in fonts, then it'd be "../stylesheets/yourfile.html" or if it's all in one folder, "yourfile.html". If you're trying to put down `C:\Users\myself\desktop\folder\file.htm` it's not going to work.

Comment: I have done that but the links don't work, it just sits there. but if I copy the HTML file link and paste it in chrome it works/loads fine for the file name/location I have in the code.

Comment: Internet Explorer is outdated and a pain in the butt. I wouldn't worry about it as long as it works fine in Chrome/Opera/Mozilla

Comment: Yes but the issue is I have an HTA I am trying to run and chrome trys to have you save it but with IE I can get it to load the HTA that is hosted on my side. Thats the issue

Comment: Okay, go ahead and edit your post explaining EXACTLY what you just said. Your question is a little too broad. This way the next person who comes along who actually has experience with HTA can help you without having to dig through the comments to figure out exactly that is you want.

Comment: The thing is its not just the HTA, the HTA is why I need it in IE. NO hrefs are working in IE with this code. It will only work if I open it in chrome for some reason, but I did add it as well.

Comment: Local files should use the `file://` protocol and should use _forward_ slashes `/` not _back_ slashes `\\`` even when on Windows.  You should post what you _actually_ have, not somthing "as an example" — even after your edit you still show `<a href="google.com" ...>` which won't work, so it becomes a distraction to your question.

Comment: okay sorry fixed. But the thing is why would it matter if its // and not \\ as it works with \\ just fine in chrome. But when selecting it in IE it does nothing, it acts like their is no href or link going anywhere but hovering it shows it up just fine.

Comment: The _web standard_ is forward slashes, and will be portable. Backslashes are windows-specific.  However, interestingly, in my Chrome browser on Mac OS X, using `file:\\\Users\mydir\notes.txt` works, but Chrome immediately translates it to `file:///Users/mydir/notes.txt` before loading it. A further note: the Windows filesystem, and DOS before it, were perfectly happy having paths delimited with `/` instead of `\\`` ... it was only the command-line processor `command.com` and later `cmd.exe` that objected to `/` — because those used it for an _option/flag_ delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="c:\Program Files (x86)\Futuremark\SystemInfo" target="_blank"><span>Click Me</span></a>
```

is a folder uri. IE will ignore it to prevent just any website from accessing the local file system.(shell)... if an attacker gains access to your computers file system, then they gain access to other sensitive information.

IE used to allow

```
<iframe src="c:\"/>
```

but that has now been patched....

see the vendors website https://www.futuremark.com/ for advice on using their desktop application with web browsers... usually interaction between IE and a desktop application is done using an ActiveX control.. eg. Adobe PDF reader. Web pages then can use scripting to launch and interact with the desktop product. IE has security zones .... other browsers have per site security settings....

You could also use a browser extension in IE that would open the futuremark folders in a shell folder instead of in a browser frame. The software vendor may already have one that you can install in IE and chrome and FX.

Answer (score 0):

you must add a http:// in your links 

   like this :

```html
<li><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><span>Google</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Now that StackOverflow is working again, in comments OP said everything was local. I'm a little confused as to why he's complaining about local files not working in IE. I mean, it only really matters if it doesn't work online, but just letting you know so you don't get a downvote or something stupid.

Comment: please read the asked question above. I stated im not even trying to do an actual link but rather access a file .

Comment: what type of file? There are restrictions on running active content from files on your computer (or shares).... publish your project to a web server (localhost or companyserver). PDF documents are opened by third party ActiveX controls in MSIE eg. Adobe PDF Reader.